# USB devices don't work on other ports

Tags: windows, usb, drivers

Is there a way that windows can use the driver of a USB device on any USB Port (just about) that is available on my computer.

I'd need this because if the USB device is plugged into other ports and Windows is at the login screen, my USB devices wont work.

Windows creates duplicate drivers for each USB port that the device is plugged into currently, which is the norm, but is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Windows already loads the driver on which ever port it is plugged into.

It sounds like the driver for your USB controller might be causing more problems than the device itself. I can't really say much else unless you give us some more details about the device and system you're using.

Comment: Windows makes a driver but for any other port the USB device is not on but was plugged into it still keeps the driver but as a phantom driver.fi lets say I have 5 usb ports, and plug it into each one, there will be 4 phantom and one normal driver unless I leave all 5 ports empty at the end

Note that windows has done this on several of my computers